# Проблема с передачей значения переменной

Tags: java

Работаю в Android Studio, приложение викторина. У меня каждый уровень прописан в отдельном классе. В классе первого уровня создал переменную, и за каждый верный ответ должно прибавляться к этой переменной по +1.

```
        public int ver; // в начале класса
        numOne.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener ( ) {
        @Override
        public void onClick ( View v ) {
            try {
                numOne.setBackground ( getResources ( ).getDrawable ( R.drawable.right_answer ) );
                ver=0; // только в одном классе это прописано
                ver++; // только в одном классе это прописано
                // далее писал l1.ver++;

                numTwo.setEnabled ( false );
                numThree.setEnabled ( false );
                Intent intent = new Intent ( SevenClassL1.this , SevenClassL2.class );
                startActivity ( intent );
                finish ( );
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
            }
        }
    } );
```

(так у меня прописано 8 уровней, и за каждый верный ответ к переменной ver прибавлялось по 1)

На последнем уровне обращаюсь к этой переменной и передаю значение этой переменной textview.

```
    SevenClassL1 l1 = new SevenClassL1 ();

    TextView verno = ( TextView ) findViewById ( R.id.verno );
    verno.setText("Verno "+l1.ver);
```

Выводит 0. Что я делаю не так, и может ли это как то работать? (Опыта программирования на Java почти нет, если что. Учить вынудил школьный проект). Помогите :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никакого обращения к переменной на последнем уровне нет. Вот здесь

```
SevenClassL1 l1 = new SevenClassL1 ();
```

создается новый объект класса, а не используется уже имеющийся. Образно говоря, вы записываете результаты в одну тетрадку, а потом хотите прочитать их из другой.

Comment: А как по другому можно в конце кол-во ошибок вывести на экран, не подскажите?

Comment: передавать значение между активити через putExtra/getIntExtra, например